# iPad - Highcharts interferes with links in the drop down

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/cwNQu/5/ - With Highcharts call
http://jsfiddle.net/cwNQu/6/ - Without Highcharts call

On iPad, you can tap "USER" and the drop down will show, but any attempt to click the links within the drop down after it is displayed will simply close the drop down.

If you remove the Highchart code the drop down and links will work properly.

I'm truly at a loss at to what in Highcharts could interfere with a CSS drop down. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

The chart code was taken from one of Highcharts examples:

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">'+
                'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value / 1000 +'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 1940,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USA',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6 , 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 ]
        }, {
            name: 'USSR/Russia',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null , null , null ,null,
            5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
            4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
            15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
            33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
            35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
            21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepared example which use a liitle bit differentt solution for show/hide menu and catch click event.

```
$('#menu li.first').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $siblings = $(this).siblings('li'); 

if($siblings.is(':visible'))
    $siblings.hide();
else
    $siblings.show();

$('#menu li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('#info').text($(this).text());
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/cwNQu/12/

but works in the iPad / touch devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sebastian and you are indeed right, that will solve the issue, but I would rather not cover up the problem with JS. My concern is with what Highcharts is doing to interfere with basic css on iPad.